# Neurolab provide many training samples for network newff

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, neural-network

I need a network that will return me some points that are representation of a curve (lets assume that these are just points from -1 to 1). 
I have 4 learning sets (very simplified example provided):

> **Input**: [1,2,3,4 ... 1190] **Target**: [0.1, 0.2, ... 1.0] 
>   **Input**: [2,3,4,5 ... 1190]   **Target**: [0.11, 0.21, ... 1.0]
>   **Input**: [0,3,1,4 ... 1190]   **Target**: [0.01, 0.23, ... 1.0]
>   **Input**: [0.1,0.3,0.5,1 ... 1190] **Target**: [0.5, 0.3, ... 1.0]

And i want to train the perceptron multilayer network using all of the above sets, but all examples of training that I've found were for one set of data => one expected output. 
How can I train network using many datasets?

I tried providing all of that in form of one numpy array but I suppose that neurolab takes only the first result from it. 
If You would like to look at my code, here is it:
https://github.com/emilswiderek/mgr/blob/master/analysis/network.py
I am talking about the '*trainNetwork*' method in **network.py** file.

Thanks in advance for any help.